# Using Spring data JPA with MS SQL server

Tags: spring-data-jpa

I am setting up an app using Spring data JPA, Hibernate and MS SQL Server and unfortunately, I got a beat messed up with the configurations.

I hope someone here code make things clearer:.

This is my mvc-dispatcher.xml which is the application context:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.yyy.yyy" />

<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:db.properties"/>


<!--  DATA BASE -->
<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="generateDdl" value="true" />
            <property name="database" value="SQL_SERVER" />
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="punit" />
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClass}" /> 
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" /> 
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.user}" /> 
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.pwd}" />
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>

<jpa:repositories base-package="com.yyy.yyy.yyy.repository"/>

<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Now, I also have a persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="punit">     
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="${jdbc.driverClass}" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="${jdbc.user}" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="${jdbc.pwd}" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop" /> 
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

I don't understand where should I put the DB connection data?
And I also cant connect to the DB (I get connection refused) - I am getting exception at server startup.

My project runs on Tomcat and I used https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-data-jpa-examples as a template.

**EDIT**
I managed to overcome the problems and publish to tomcat successfully,by removing the persistence XML file and use only the spring context file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xsi:schemaLocation="         http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans              http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd         http://www.springframework.org/schema/context          http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd         http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa          http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd         http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx          http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">
   <context:component-scan base-package="yyy.yyy.yyy" />
   <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:db.properties" />
   <!-- DATA BASE -->
   <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
      <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
      <property name="packagesToScan" value="yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy.domain" />
      <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
         <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="generateDdl" value="false" />
            <property name="showSql" value="true" />
            <property name="database" value="SQL_SERVER" />
            <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect" />
         </bean>
      </property>
   </bean>
   <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
      <property name="driverClassName" value="net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver" />
      <property name="url" value="jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=db" />
      <property name="username" value="yyy" />
      <property name="password" value="yyyyy" />
   </bean>
   <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
      <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
      <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
   </bean>
   <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
   <jpa:repositories base-package="yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy.repository" />
   <!-- MVC -->
   <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
      <property name="prefix">
         <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
      </property>
      <property name="suffix">
         <value>.jsp</value>
      </property>
   </bean>
</beans>
```

The app now loads fine, but when I use my repository and call save, I get connection refused exception.

Anyone knows why?

Help please.
Idob

Answer (score 1):

You are refering to `db.properites` file here:`<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:db.properties"/>`
Where is it located in the project?

Comment: So when you start up the application does it write in the log, that it has found it? Something similar to
`INFO  org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer - Loading properties file from...`

Comment: I also mislead you, the db.properties file is at the src/main/resources folder.

Comment: I put the properties data in the datasource configuration (without using properties file) and still - connection refused. example: <property name="username" value="yyy" />

Comment: I think the connection url is incorrect, instead of `databaseName=db` you should use `database=db` (if the name of the database is indeed `db`
See [What is the URL format used by jTDS?](http://jtds.sourceforge.net/faq.html#urlFormat)